# how to solve time-out HYT00 teraData

Tags: sql, timeout, teradata, query-timeout

i have been working on asp.net and charts and i want to run a query that would display data in charts.

however, the query takes a lot of time and every time the error comes that time-out.

[image]

the query is :

```
select    Colum, 

SUM(CASE WHEN column1 = 1 THEN column2 END)mins, 
 SUM(column3)AS rev, 
SUM(column4)AS qty

from table1 
where column5  between Date-10 and Date 
group by 1 
order by column5;
```

how can i increase the time out value? please help!

Answer (score 1):

There's no query timeout setting (only a login timeout) in Teradata's ODBC driver when you use the ODBC Data Source Administrator, it must be set by the applcation using the SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT attribute with SQLSetStmtAttr().

And the default is zero, which means no timeout, so this must be applied by Visual Studio (global default automatically applied to all connections?) or your program.